# Passing object id to a flow using a custom controller

Tags: apex, controller, flow

I'm a clicks not code guy building a custom controller based on some code I found in the web. The controller is to be part of a visualforce page that launches when a button on the contact page is clicked.  The controller enables me to pass the results of the flow (a new record ID) through to the visualforce page - which I will then be able to use to direct the finishLocation.

I need to access the originating contact (this record) to pass the contact ID to the flow - which the flow needs. How can I do that?

```
public class createOpportunityController{  
// Instanciate the Flow for use by the Controller - linked by VF interview attribute  

public Flow.Interview.create_Lead_From_Contact flowInstance {get;set;}  

// Set the page reference accessor methods  
public PageReference finishLocation {  
    get {  
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/' + newRecordId);  
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);  
        return pageRef;  
        }  
    set { finishLocation = value; }  
}  


// Set the accessor methods for the flow output variable  

public String newRecordId {  
    get {  
        String strTemp = '';  
            if(flowInstance != null) {  
            strTemp =   
string.valueOf(flowInstance.getVariableValue('leadID'));  
            }  
        return strTemp;  
    }  
        set { newRecordId = value; }  
    }  
}
```